# What is the conceptual difference between topic extraction and text categorization?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, categorical-data, topic-modeling

I'm confused that very similar services for text mining have different names, like topic extraction and text categorization/classification. What is the conceptual difference between them?

Topic extraction example:
https://www.uclassify.com/browse/uclassify/topics?input=Text

Categorization example:
https://dandelion.eu/semantic-text/text-classification-demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topic Model approaches (Topic Extraction) are unsupervised approaches. So, you don't need to know that each document belongs to what categories  (classes) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model]. 
Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) is a method for Topic Modeling. LDA divides the documents into topics and assigns a name to the topics. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation]
Topic Model needs the number of output clusters as the same as clustering methods. But they assign a topic name to each output cluster.
In contrast to Topic Model approaches, Document Classification approaches (Categorization) are supervised. So, they need the class labels. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification]

Comment: But what if the set of topic names is predefined? What is the name of this task?

Comment: Since you know the number of classes, it is a classification problem.